# Is it acceptable/desire If I throw an error from callee rather than from caller

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Is it acceptable/desire If I throw an error from callee rather than from caller? Or should I get the error info from callee and then throw the exception from caller? Which one is preferred/desire way?

```
public static List<ProductBuilder> GetProductBuilders(GetProductsRequest productsRequest)
{
    List<ProductBuilder> productBuilders = new List<ProductBuilder>();
    ...
    ... // Some logics to populate productBuilders

   if (productBuilders.Count == 0)
    {
        Logger.LogMessage(productsRequest.SessionId, "No ProductBuilders were created.");
        throw new ProductException(ProductException.ExceptionCode.SaveFailed, "No Service has qualified.");
    }

    return productBuilders;
}
```

Comment: Is an empty result really (always) an error?

Comment: Agree with @HenkHolterman, in my opinion empty collections should be treated for what they are not an as exceptional case. I want to add that when possible an empty collection is always preferable to returning a null. For deepen the last concept, read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/04/TheBCLalreadyhasaMaybemonad/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO,

Your framework class code should throw exception if any your class is expecting some parameters from the client , otherwise client should handle the output returned.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is *stick to the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)*.

In the example you provided the method `GetProductBuilders` has (at least) two responsibilities:

1. Populate the collection of objects
2. Validate the result count

If you refactor your code to:

```
public static List<ProductBuilder> PopulateProductBuilders(...)
{
    // Logic to populate the collection
}

public static List<ProductBuilder> GetProductBuilders(GetProductsRequest productsRequest)
{
    var productBuilders = PopulateProductBuilders();
    if(!productBuilders.Any())
    {
        Logger.LogMessage(productsRequest.SessionId, "No ProductBuilders were created.");
        throw new ProductException(ProductException.ExceptionCode.SaveFailed, "No Service has qualified.");
    }
}
```

then it becomes clear which method should perform the validation on empty list and throw the exception.

In other words, if you separate the responsibilities of your methods you'll have a better picture of where to throw exceptions.

Comment: SRP is only for classes right? Isn't it? Also If I start to apply SRP in methods level, would my class endup with LOTS of methods which become tedious to maintain? Your opinion pls

Comment: @Al.Net, SRP should be applied to methods also; a method should only be responsible for one operation. If you have lots of methods in a single class then you should group them by functonality and move the groups into separate classes. And about maintenance: it is a lot easyer to maintain a simple method than a overly complicated one; also, smaller methods improve readability and code-reuse.